# Does logger(1) command belong to util-linux?

Tags: debian, logger, util-linux

Does logger(1) command belong to util-linux? it is not shown in https://manpages.debian.org/testing/util-linux/index.html, but in https://manpages.debian.org/testing/bsdutils/logger.1.en.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of util-linux, but Debian has packaged it in the [bsdutils](https://packages.debian.org/buster/bsdutils) package. There's a pile of other packages that are also compiled from [the util-linux source package](https://packages.debian.org/source/buster/util-linux), apart from `util-linux` and `bsdutils`.

You can see the (installed) binary package a file belongs to with `dpkg -S`:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/logger
bsdutils: /usr/bin/logger
```

`apt-cache showsrc package` should show the corresponding source package, but I just looked at the online package search; the source package is mentioned in the side bar.

Comment: Are the packages listed in https://packages.debian.org/source/buster/util-linux subsets of util-linux?

Comment: @Ben, subsets of the upstream util-linux, pretty much, yes. They probably split the tools in multiple packages so that you don't have to e.g. install fdisk if you don't want to. So the binary package "util-linux" is also a subset of the source package "util-linux". I'm not so sure why they've bothered with the split between bsdutils and util-linux (the binary package), since they're both marked as Essential anyway, so you can't leave either out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apt-file` to get the package name providing `logger`:

```
$ which logger
/usr/bin/logger

$ apt-file search /usr/bin/logger

bsdutils: /usr/bin/logger                 
loggerhead: /usr/bin/loggerhead-serve
```

From the output `bsdutils` provide `logger` command.

To install `apt-file`:

```
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```